# AWS Cognito - Enabling MFA | Error: MFA cannot be turned off if an SMS role is configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

Im trying to enable MFA for an existing AWS Cognito user pool.
Im editing the user-pool configuration, but trying to save the new configuration results in a `MFA cannot be turned off if an SMS role is configured` error (see picture). I don't understand that error message, and Google is no help.

**Question:** What am I do wrong, how can I enable MFA for an existing user pool?

[image]

Comment: which aws region are you using?

Comment: Ireland (eu-west-1)

Comment: weird, I guess that you already chose optional for MFA. In my case, it doesn't work in eu-central-1 but for eu-west-1 it's ok.

Comment: And you probably also need to increase the your AWS monthly spending limit.

Comment: The SNS spending limit is already increased, I don’t think that’s the problem. I solved the issue by exporting all users, creating a new user pool with MFA enabled and then importing the users. This solution would probably not be desirable if the system contained many users and high traffic.

Comment: Looks like its an AWS console bug see: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=283152 . "We are working towards fixing this issue in Cognito Console. Meanwhile as a work around, you can use AWS CLI to setup your user pool." I am suffering from the same issue in eu-west-2

Answer (score 10):

Go to IAM and make sure you didn't accidently created an SMS role. 
Under the step :

```
You must provide a role to allow Amazon Cognito to send SMS messages
```

If you press **Create Role** then this will generate the error you mentioned. I guess in order to continue you need to properly configure your SMS.

To solve this issue I had to remove an **SMS role (IAM)** linked to my Users Pool.

So by removing the SMS role I was able to continue the creation of the new User Pool.

You can do that by signing to your console. Go to **IAM** on the left side under the dashboard go to **Roles**. Select from the list the SMS role associated to your User pool and delete it.

Comment: 3 years later and it's incredible how difficult they make this process

Answer (score 6):

The SNSRole is added automatically, can't be changed by any available parameter and can't be modified later. The current workaround is to manually modify the yaml configuration and remove that part.

- amplify add auth
- go through all the config
- open the file backend/auth/<name>/<name>-cloudformation-template.yml
- remove SNSRole row in Resources and SmsConfiguration in Resources > UserPool > Properties
- amplify push

from: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2906

Comment: it seems this path no longer exists. I could not find it in my project.

Comment: @Min are you sure ? the path depends on the name you've chosen.

Comment: Yes I am sure. This is what I see: amplify/backend/auth/<name>/build/<name>-cloudformation-template.json . I remove mentioned resources from this json template but it does not detect any change. It seems you mentioning different patch and your template is yml

Answer (score 1):

The provided solution (removing the role manually) didn't work for me.

I found a solution from the amplify cli.

Run this

```
amplify update auth
```

One of the questions is if you want to disable MFA.
And then

```
amplify push auth
```

to move your changes to the cloud